# Trying to output information from xml api using nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, api, nokogiri

I'm trying to output information to a web page taken from an XML transport api for a college project. I'm using ruby on rails and the nokogiri gem. I can take in the information but when I try to output it on the results page it is just blank.

The below method for taking in the api information is in the relevant rails controller file.

```
def results
require 'nokogiri'

@doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getAllStationsXML"))
end
```

I can see the xml information is being passed to the view. When I just put `<%= @doc %>` in the view it causes the information in xml format to print out on the page.

However, I obviously need to format it correctly. I have the code below in the view and have also tried putting it in the controller method (minus the <% %> notation) but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<% @doc.xpath('//StationId').each do |station_element| %>

<%= station_element.text %>

<% end %>
```

This is what the XML data looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfObjStation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/">
  <objStation>
    <StationDesc>Belfast Central</StationDesc>
    <StationAlias />
    <StationLatitude>54.6123</StationLatitude>
    <StationLongitude>-5.91744</StationLongitude>
    <StationCode>BFSTC</StationCode>
    <StationId>228</StationId>
  </objStation>
  <objStation>
    <StationDesc>Lisburn</StationDesc>
    <StationAlias />
    <StationLatitude>54.514</StationLatitude>
    <StationLongitude>-6.04327</StationLongitude>
    <StationCode>LBURN</StationCode>
    <StationId>238</StationId>
  </objStation>
</ArrayOfObjStation>
```

I'd appreciate if someone could indicate what code I need to print out just certain parts of the xml data, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML at http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getAllStationsXML has [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) (*I modified the xml to reflect what is returned by API*)

You need to use namespace prefix in xpath notation to get it work.

replace `@doc.xpath('//StationId')` with `@doc.xpath('//xmlns:StationId')` to fix it.